Impossible to reproduce the clickup carousel animation
its seems impossible to reproduce the carousel of clickup saas... Anyone can help me please ?
the carousel
https://clickup.com/
There is my actual code :


const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
const visibleItems = 7; // Le nombre d'éléments visibles
let currentIndex = Math.floor(items.length / 3); // Index de l'élément central initial

function updateCarousel(newIndex) {
  const middleIndex = Math.floor(visibleItems / 2);
  const offset = newIndex - currentIndex;

  if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= items.length) return;

  const itemWidth = items[0].offsetWidth + 60;

  // Déplacer le carrousel pour centrer le nouvel élément cliqué
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${-(newIndex - middleIndex) * itemWidth}px)`;

  // Mettre à jour la classe active
  items[currentIndex].classList.remove('active');
  items[newIndex].classList.add('active');

  currentIndex = newIndex; // Mettre à jour l'index courant
}

// Ajouter l'événement de clic à chaque élément du carrousel
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    updateCarousel(index);
  });
});

// Initialiser la position du carrousel
items[currentIndex].classList.add('active');
carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${-(currentIndex - Math.floor(visibleItems / 2))     * (items[0].offsetWidth + 60)}px)`;
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
}

.carousel-item:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fade-left,
.fade-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fade-left {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(240, 240, 245, 1), rgba(240, 240, 245, 0));
}

.fade-right {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(240, 240, 245, 1), rgba(240, 240, 245, 0));
}

.fa-duotone {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #333;
}
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="fade-left"></div>
  <div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-image"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-subtitles" style="--fa-primary-color: #000;"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-link"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-file-code"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-file-pen"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-wand-magic-sparkles"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-circle-question"></i></div>
      <!-- Dupliquer les éléments pour créer un effet continu -->
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-image"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-subtitles" style="--fa-primary-color: #000;"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-link"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-file-code"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-file-pen"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-wand-magic-sparkles"></i></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-circle-question"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade-right"></div>
</div>



But i have already try many things.
So, to recap, I'm trying to create a carousel where 7 elements are visible at the same time, with the 4th element always centered. When a user clicks on an element to the right or left of the center, that element should move to take the central position. For example, if I click on an element that's to the right of the center, that element should move to the center. The same behavior should occur if an element to the left of the center is clicked. The movement should be smooth and maintain the order of the elements, without scrolling through the entire carousel. Basically, just like ClickUp.
Thanks for any help !

Try & test
Moving Based on Initial and Target Index
Problem: Movement was fixed in increments of 7 items, causing inconsistent shifts and incorrect centering of items.
Absolute Pixel Calculation for Movement
Problem: Used fixed pixel values for movement, resulting in incorrect display and misalignment of centered items.
Using currentOffset for Position Calculation
Problem: Incorrect initial positioning led to misalignment and improper centering of items.
CSS Animation for Pixel Movement
Problem: CSS animations were out of sync with JavaScript calculations, causing display issues.
Recalculation Based on Clicks
Problem: Miscalculated the pixel movement needed, leading to improper centering and alignment.
Initial Centering with Movement Calculation
Problem: Incorrect initial centering resulted in the wrong element being centered and displayed.
Direct translateX Manipulation
Problem: Directly manipulating translateX with incorrect values led to inconsistent movement and centering.
And many other things...

It would be easier if you had 3 copies.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

New Solution
The previous solution -- listed below this one -- was a bit more difficult as it was made to avoid cloning the buttons in the carousel. The previous solution is the better one (assuming you can correct the timings); this solution is easier and reliable, but it requires cloning the buttons which isn't friendly to event listeners and isn't that great for performance (that might not matter here).
In this solution, each button is cloned twice -- as was recommended initially in the comments of your question by A Haworth. This makes animating using only CSS possible, as extra copies of the buttons populate either side when the original leaves the user's view.
I added a comment for the few most notable lines in the CSS and JavaScript, but I'll describe what's happening here: I am moving the first or last elements within the carousel to the other side so the desired button is actually the center element, then the position of each button is calculated and applied to it. The buttons that were moved to the other side are hidden until the animation is over (made visible again using setTimeout()).


addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 var [carousel, window] = ['#carousel', '#window'].map(v => document.querySelector(v));

 // Place your button events here.
 for(var child of carousel.children)
  child.addEventListener('click', function() { window.innerHTML = `Your ${this.innerHTML} content here!`; });

 var center = () =>  Math.floor(carousel.children.length/2);
 carousel.center = child => {
  var resize;
  if(!child) {
   child = document.querySelector('#carousel > .center');
   resize = true;
  }
  var index = Array.from(carousel.children).indexOf(child);
  if(!index) return;
  carousel.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  if(!resize) {
   for(var i = index-center(); i != 0; i > 0 ? i-- : i++) {
    if(i > 0) {
     carousel.firstElementChild.classList.add('hidden');
     carousel.append(carousel.firstElementChild);
    } else {
     carousel.lastElementChild.classList.add('hidden');
     carousel.prepend(carousel.lastElementChild);
    }
   }
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < carousel.children.length; i++) {
   carousel.children[i].style.left = `calc(${carousel.offsetWidth/2}px - var(--icon-width) / 2 - var(--icon-width) * ${i-center()})`;
   carousel.children[i].classList.remove('center');
  }
  child.classList.add('center');
  setTimeout(() => {
   for(var child of carousel.children) child.classList.remove('hidden');
   carousel.style.pointerEvents = '';
  }, 500);
 }
 var children = Array.from(carousel.children);
 var clone = () => children.map(child => {
  var v = child.cloneNode(true);
  v.original = child;

  // If your buttons have more event listeners than "click", copy the following line and change the "click"s to the desired event. You need this because event listeners are not cloneable.
  v.addEventListener('click', function(event) { this.original.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); });
  v.classList.remove('center');
  return v;
 });
 carousel.prepend(...clone());
 carousel.append(...clone());
 for(var i = 0; i < carousel.children.length; i++)
  carousel.children[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { this.parentElement.center(this); });
 
 // Stack Overflow doesn't like the resize event listener, but this is necessary to keep the elements positioned correctly if the window is resized. Uncomment the following line if using this code.
 // addEventListener('resize', carousel.center);
 carousel.center();
});
* {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html {
 overflow: hidden;
}
body {
 /* Change the 9 in --icon-width to define how many icons are shown at once. */
 --icon-width: calc(100vw / 9);
 --icon-height: 4rem;
 background: radial-gradient(circle at 60% 30%, #FFFD, #FFF0), radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 10% 90%, #F7A 50%, #55F);
}
#carousel {
 mask: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, white 25%, white 75%, transparent);
 width: 100%;
 height: calc(var(--icon-height) * 2);
 overflow: hidden;
 button {
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  width: var(--icon-width);
  height: 100%;
  font-size: calc(var(--icon-height) * 0.8);
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 500ms, left 500ms;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em #0005;
  user-select: none;
  &.center {
   transform: scale(1.5);
   pointer-events: none;
  }
  &:hover:not(:active) {
   transform: scale(1.5);
   transition: transform 50ms, left 500mx;
  }
 }
}
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
#window {
 margin: 0 10%;
 padding: 1em;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #0005;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
 body {
  /* As mentioned above, the 9 was changed here to 3, so only 3 icons are shown in portrait mode. */
  --icon-width: calc(100vw / 3);
  --icon-height: 3rem;
 }
}
<div id='carousel'>
 <button>&#9703;</button>
 <button>&#9685;</button>
 <button>&#9711;</button>
 <button>&#9672;</button>
 <button class='center'>&#9674;</button>
 <button>&#9648;</button>
 <button>&#9635;</button>
 <button>&#9639;</button>
 <button>&#9683;</button>
</div>
<div id="window">Your &#9674; content here!</div>



Using this solution, and the @media (orientation: portrait) CSS selector, you should be able to make the carousel more friendly for differently sized screens. Hopefully this is helpful you to!
Previous Solution
I managed to make a working carousel, although it isn't perfect. It also relies on the entire carousel being visible, but hopefully this helps you to create your own solution!
To make the carousel, I had to use custom animations and timings for each button. Click here for more information on how to create animations on elements using JavaScript. Click here to see more about the Animations API. The Animation object returned from element.animate() also has a useful Animation.finished promise that you can use to execute code once the animation has finished. I didn't use that here, but it's a useful feature.
For each button, I changed the order I wanted it to be in and calculated its 'left' style for where it should be in that position. During that calculation for each button, if the button should leave the screen to go to the other side, I took the ratio of how many positions it would need to traverse to leave the screen, and how many positions it would need to traverse to get to its final position. I used that ratio for the timing between moving it off screen, teleporting it to the other side, and moving it back on the screen.
I know this isn't the most straightforward answer, but a carousel seems to be a tricky thing, so hopefully the following code can put you on the right track:


// Wait for the elements to load.
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

 // Get the div elements with the id's "carousel" and "window".
 var [carousel, window] = ['#carousel', '#window'].map(v => document.querySelector(v));

 // Get the number of children in the carousel (9).
 var visible = carousel.children.length;

 // Set the halfway point (4).
 var center = Math.floor(visible/2);

 // Create a function that can get the appropriate value for the 'left' style based on an element's position.
 var left = value => `calc(${100/(visible*2)+(100/visible)*value}% - var(--icon) / 2)`;

 // Make it easier to keep track of what order the buttons should be in by assigning each one a number.
 for(var i = 0; i < carousel.children.length; i++) {
  // Using a getter and setter to make changing the order easy.
  Object.defineProperty(carousel.children[i], 'order', {
   get() { return this.place; },
   set(v) {
    while(v < 0) v+= this.parentElement.children.length;
    while(v >= this.parentElement.children.length) v-= this.parentElement.children.length;
    this.place = v;
   }
  });

  // Set the position (order) of the buttons to what they currently are.
  carousel.children[i].order = i;

  // Position the elements appropriately using our left() function.
  carousel.children[i].style.left = left(i);
 }

 // This function will take the given button, center it, and move every other button appropriately.
 carousel.center = button => {
  // How much the button needs to move to reach the center.
  var offset = center-button.order;

  // For each child, see if it's outside the range of how many elements are visible, and make a custom animation to move it in the right direction, teleport it to the other side, then continue its movement.
  for(var child of carousel.children) {
   // The .center class is almost entirely visual.
   child.classList.remove('center');

   // Get the current order of the current child, and the new order before it's modified through our setter function.
   var order = {
    old: child.order,
    new: child.order+offset
   }
   // Set the child order to its new position so we can get the left() value it should land on.
   child.order = order.new;

   // If the child is moving left off of the screen, move it off the screen, teleport it to the other side, then move it back onto the screen.
   if(order.new < 0) child.animate(
    {left: [left(order.old), left(-1), left(visible), left(child.order)],
     easing: 'ease',
     offset: [0, (center+order.new)/center, (center+order.new)/center, 1]},
    { duration: 500, fill: 'forwards' });

   // If the child is moving right off of the screen, move it off the screen, teleport it to the other side, then move it back onto the screen.
   else if(order.new >= visible) child.animate(
    {left: [left(order.old), left(visible), left(-1), left(child.order)],
     easing: 'ease',
     offset: [0, (center+(visible-order.new))/center, (center+(visible-order.new))/center, 1]},
    { duration: 500, fill: 'forwards' });

   // If the child isn't moving off of the screen, move it directly to its new position.
   else child.animate(
    {left: [left(order.old), left(child.order)],
     easing: 'ease'},
    { duration: 500, fill: 'forwards' });
  }
  button.classList.add('center');
 };

 // Add a 'click' eventListener to each button making it center when clicked.
 // Additional eventListeners can be added after this for individual custom button functions.
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#carousel > button')).forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.parentElement.center(this);
   window.innerHTML = `Your ${this.innerHTML} content here!`;
  });
 });
});
* {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 --icon: 5rem;
 background: radial-gradient(circle at 60% 30%, #FFFD, #FFF0), radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 10% 90%, #F7A 50%, #55F);
}
#carousel {
 mask: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, white 25%, white 75%, transparent);
 padding: calc(var(--icon) / 4) 0;
 height: calc(var(--icon) * 2);
 overflow: hidden;
 button {
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  width: var(--icon);
  height: var(--icon);
  font-size: calc(var(--icon) * 0.8);
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em #0005;
  user-select: none;
  &.center {
   transform: scale(1.5);
   pointer-events: none;
  }
  &:hover:not(:active) {
   transform: scale(1.5);
   transition: transform 50ms;
  }
 }
}
#window {
 margin: 0 10%;
 padding: 1em;
 width: 80%;
 height: calc(100% - var(--icon));
 border-radius: 0.5em;
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #0005;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
<div id='carousel'>
 <button>&#9703;</button>
 <button>&#9685;</button>
 <button>&#9711;</button>
 <button>&#9672;</button>
 <button class='center'>&#9674;</button>
 <button>&#9648;</button>
 <button>&#9635;</button>
 <button>&#9639;</button>
 <button>&#9683;</button>
</div>
<div id="window">Your &#9674; content here!</div>



Hopefully this information is useful to you!

Thank you so much!
This is perfect!
Just one question, why does the animation on the left not appear as smooth as on the right (it "jumps" on the left)? And how can I smooth out this animation (the right one that works)? Thanks!

Also, how to do that for responsive mobile (the most important), like uclick, he have 3 elements for mobile ... thank you very much for your help, i try, really, but I can't do it

I have added a new solution to my answer. Hopefully it answers both of those concerns!

Yes, thats perfect, thx !!!
